# Drag And Drop Image in Fix size Layout Android

Tags: android, drag-and-drop

I am able to drag Image but when I drag image my image size keep changing. Image size is not fixed.  please let me know where I am wrong. When I drag image it keeps changing size of perticular image. There something about layout params but I am not able to fix it.

Xml  of my drag area.

```
<LinearLayout
          android:id="@+id/vg1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/scrollView2"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:background="@drawable/shape" >


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/dragimg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:src="@drawable/log_off_button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

My Drag Image code:

```
        OnTouchListener dragt = new OnTouchListener()
    {
    @Override       
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
    {

         LinearLayout.LayoutParams par = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(v.getLayoutParams());
         v.setLayoutParams(par);  
    switch(v.getId())
    {//What is being touched                                    
    case R.id.dragimg:      
    {//Which action is being taken      
    switch(event.getAction())           
    {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:           
    {       
        par.topMargin = (int)event.getRawY() + windowheight - (vg.getHeight()/2);       
        par.leftMargin = (int) ((int)event.getRawX() +windowwidth - (vg.getWidth()));

    v.setLayoutParams(par);
    break;  
    }//inner case MOVE
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:                     
    {

        par.topMargin = (int)event.getRawY()+ windowheight - (vg.getHeight()/2);
        par.leftMargin = (int) ((int)event.getRawX() + windowwidth - (vg.getWidth()));
    v.setLayoutParams(par);
    break;
    }//inner case UP
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
    {
//  par.height = 60;
//  par.width = 60;
    v.setLayoutParams(par);
    break;          
    }
    }
    break;
    }
    }
    return true;        
    }
    };
```

Please let me know where I am wrong or better way to do this. There will be only 1 image for drag and drop.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue,  Here is the solution I found:

```
private View.OnTouchListener onTouchListener() {
        return new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {

                final int x = (int) event.getRawX();
                final int y = (int) event.getRawY();

                switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)
                                view.getLayoutParams();

                        xDelta = x - lParams.leftMargin;
                        yDelta = y - lParams.topMargin;
                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view
                                .getLayoutParams();
                        layoutParams.leftMargin = x - xDelta;
                        layoutParams.topMargin = y - yDelta;
                        layoutParams.rightMargin = -250;
                        layoutParams.bottomMargin = -250;
                        view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                        break;
                }
                image_layout.invalidate();
                return true;
            }
        };
    }
```

Adding this two lines is most important:

```
layoutParams.rightMargin = -250;
layoutParams.bottomMargin = -250;
```

This will make imageView unable to change its size when it goes to the corners in top-right or bottom-right.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: hello i want drag image in fix size of area how can i do that?